# Rust Implement Iterator

Tags: rust, iterator, stack

So I am currently learning Rust and have a question on how to implement a non-consuming Iterator.
I programmed a Stack:

```
struct Node<T>{
    data:T,
    next:Option<Box<Node<T>>>
}
pub struct Stack<T>{
    first:Option<Box<Node<T>>>
}
impl<T> Stack<T>{
    pub fn new() -> Self{
        Self{first:None}
    }
    pub fn push(&mut self, element:T){
        let old = self.first.take();
        self.first = Some(Box::new(Node{data:element, next:old}));
    }
    pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<T>{
        match self.first.take(){
            None => None,
            Some(node) =>{
                self.first = node.next;
                Some(node.data)
            }
        }
    }
    pub fn iter(self) -> StackIterator<T>{
        StackIterator{
            curr : self.first
        }
    }
}
pub struct StackIterator<T>{
    curr : Option<Box<Node<T>>>
}
impl<T> Iterator for StackIterator<T>{
    type Item = T;
    fn next (&mut self) -> Option<T>{
        match self.curr.take(){
            None => None,
            Some(node) => {
                self.curr = node.next;
                Some(node.data)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With a Stack Iterator, which is created calling the `iter()` Method on a Stack. The Problem: I had to make this `iter()` method consuming its Stack, therefore a stack is only iteratable once. How can I implement this method without consuming the Stack and without implementing the copy or clone trait?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I implement this method without consuming the Stack and without implementing the copy or clone trait?

Have StackIterator *borrow* the stack instead, and the iterator return references to the items. Something along the lines of

```
impl<T> Stack<T>{
    pub fn iter(&self) -> StackIterator<T>{
        StackIterator{
            curr : &self.first
        }
    }
}
pub struct StackIterator<'stack, T: 'stack>{
    curr : &'stack Option<Box<Node<T>>>
}
impl<'s, T: 's> Iterator for StackIterator<'s, T>{
    type Item = &'s T;
    fn next (&mut self) -> Option<&'s T>{
        match self.curr.as_ref().take() {
            None => None,
            Some(node) => {
                self.curr = &node.next;
                Some(&node.data)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(I didn't actually test this code so it's possible it doesn't work)

That's essentially what `std::iter::Iter` does (though it's implemented as a *way* lower level).

That said learning Rust by implementing linked lists [probably isn't the best idea in the world](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/), linked lists are degenerate graphs, and the borrow checker is not on very friendly terms with graphs.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works now :)
Honestly i did not know anything about the borrowing syntax with those Lifetime parameters.
Coming from C++ and Java all of this still seams kind of weird, i just could have moved on with not knowing how to solve basic linked constructor classes, but if you are used to other languages it just borders you if you don't know it.

Comment: @Sprinklerkopf Note that you'd have a similar issue in C++, you'd have to either provide `T&` or copy-construct `T`. The difference is that C++ is much more eager to assume that a type can be copy-constructed and will happily do it implicitly, where in Rust you must call something like `clone()`. The solution provided by this answer gives maximum flexibility to the user of the iterator because they can use the references if you only need read-only access, or they can clone them if they need new `T` values.

Comment: @Sprinklerkopf you really want to read the Rust book, and the linked lists tutorial, then. Borrowing is pretty central to rust and trying to learn it via trial and error is *extremely* frustrating: the compiler tries to help, but as often as not the help it tries to provide will lead you down the wrong path entirely. Having at least an idea of what's happening, and of what materials to go back to, helps a lot.